# Post then change text in html nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web, post

I have a form tag in Html like then:

```
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html")
```

})

```js
app.post("/Cong",urlencodedParser,(req,res)=>{
    var a = parseInt(req.body.a);
    var b = parseInt(req.body.b);
    var c = a + b;
    res.send("Result: "+c)//This is will route to a new website, but I just want change text in my HTML
})
```

```html
 <form action="/Cong" method="post">
  A: <input type="text" name="a"><br>
  B: <input type="text" name="b"><br>
<label id="result"></label>
</form>
```

how I can change the label in HTML with id result = value C in file js when I click the button.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I'm a bit confused about the context you're trying to achieve this in.

In the browser, you would do `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = c`

But you don't display the front end code, only the backend, you'd need to call your backend end point from the front end

eg: post to  `/Cong` here's an example in Axios

```
axios.post('/Cong', {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  })
  .then(function (response) {
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = response;
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Your backend `res.send("Result: "+c)` should also read `res.send(c)` as otherwise the front end will get "Result: 3" instead of just 3